# How to sum only digits from a list using decorate?

Tags: python, function, decorator

I tried to pass a list to a function somme(calculate the sum of numbers in a list)

but i got err `unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`. 
I have decided to create *nettoyage* function to filter a list and return noly digits!

that is what i tried so far?

```py
def nettoyage(func):
    def inner(*args):
        digits = []
        for i in args:
            if(str(i).isdigit()):
                digits.append(i)
        t=tuple(digits)
        return func(*t)
    return inner

@nettoyage
def somme(l):
    s=0
    for i in l:
        s+=i
    return s #or just sum(l)

print(somme([1,2,3,4,5,'a','b'])) # -> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

> TypeError: somme() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l'

PS:I know i could use filter function or just loop over a list and accumulate only numbers a function but 
i want to know more about decorate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `args` represents all the arguments of the `func` function as a list, so to get the first one, the list of values do `args[0]`. Then no need to build a `tuple` and pass the list `digits` at a single parameter, calling `func(*t)` call like `func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and that isn't the `somme` definition

```
def nettoyage(func):
    def inner(*args):
        digits = []
        for i in args[0]:
            if str(i).isdigit():
                digits.append(i)
        return func(digits)
    return inner
```

Can be converted in a `list-comprehension`

```
def nettoyage(func):
    def inner(*args):
        return func([i for i in args[0] if str(i).isdigit()])
    return inner
```

Giving `15` not `[1,2,3,4,5]`

```
print(somme([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b']))  # -> 15
```

---

#### Note for yourself :

you could have solved **all** of that with a few printing (of `args`, of  `l`). When something isn't working with a variable : **print it**

Comment: Thank you for Answer & Note <3